# Android: using DrawerLayout and YouTubePlayerSupportFragment

Tags: android, youtube, fragment, android-appcompat, drawerlayout

I am trying to integrate in my app the [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) with the [YouTubePlayerSupportFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerSupportFragment). I would like to load fragments in the main activity using the Navigation Drawer menu.

I have downloaded "YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar" file and put in the "libs" folder. From com.android.support I've also added dependencies in build.gradle(app) file for appcompact, design and support:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.xyz.testing"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is "activity_main.xml" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context="com.test.xyz.testing.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Relative Layout" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#333333"
        ></FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    >
</ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I've added two fragments: one simple fragment and one for the YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.
This is the code for the YoutubePlayerSupportFragment (which causes the app to crash):

```
package com.test.xyz.testing;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;




public class PlayerYoutubeFrag extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment {

    private String currentVideoID = "video_id";
    private YouTubePlayer activePlayer;

    public static PlayerYoutubeFrag newInstance(String url) {

        PlayerYoutubeFrag playerYouTubeFrag = new PlayerYoutubeFrag();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("url", url);

        playerYouTubeFrag.setArguments(bundle);

        playerYouTubeFrag.init(); //This line right here

        return playerYouTubeFrag;
    }

    private void init() {

        initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_ANDROID_KEY, new OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) { }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                activePlayer = player;
                activePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    activePlayer.loadVideo(getArguments().getString("url"), 0);

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the code for the "MainActivity.java" file:

```
package com.test.xyz.testing;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import layout.SettingsFragment;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements SettingsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {



    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    String fragmentArray[] = {"Frag1", "Frag2"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_text, R.id.list_text_view, fragmentArray);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Fragment fragment;



                switch (i) {

                    case 0:
                        fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        fragment = null;
                        break;

                    default:
                        fragment = null;
                        break;
                }

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                if (fragment != null) {
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, fragment).commit();
                }
                else {
                    String video_id = "LHcP4MWABGY";
                    PlayerYoutubeFrag myFragment = PlayerYoutubeFrag.newInstance(video_id);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, myFragment).commit();
                }




            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

The Navigation Drawer works fine. Basically if i click on the first entry of the Drawer the SettingsFragment is loaded correctly. If i click on the second entry of the Drawer it should load the PlayerYoutubeFrag (which extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) passing a string of video_id. 
The app crash at the last line:

```
String video_id = "LHcP4MWABGY";
PlayerYoutubeFrag myFragment = PlayerYoutubeFrag.newInstance(video_id);
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, myFragment).commit();
```

This is the log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.test.xyz.testing, PID: 28303
      java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START pkg=com.google.android.youtube }
          at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1460)
          at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
          at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:632)
          at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.e(Unknown Source)
          at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown Source)
          at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.a(Unknown Source)
          at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
          at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Not sure how to fix this. Or could anyone point me to a working example of an app using a drawer and youtube fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Did you allow internet access in Manifest file

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

Does the device have youtube app on it?

Comment: Yes and yes. Youtube app updated to the last version